# No bb files found in layer

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I am new to Yocto and doing some starter projects. I have added my own layer called `meta-tutorial` .

I have the following recipe file inside my layer at `meta-tutorial/recipe-example/hello/hello_1.0.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://hello.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        ${CC} hello.c ${LDFLAGS} -o hello
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 hello ${D}${bindir}
}
```

The *hello.c* source file is located at `meta-tutorial/recipe-example/hello/files/hello.c`

When I source the *oe-init-build-env* script , and try to build my recipe as follows `bitbake hello_1.0.bb`, I encounter the following issues :

```
WARNING: No bb files in default matched BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-tutorial '^/home/Yocto-test/poky/meta-tutorial/'
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'hello_1.0.bb'
```

What is the problem here exactly, it's not clear?

Comment: `recipeS-example/...'

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I don't understand

Comment: look at the path again and compare it with my correction.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk. It shouldn't matter what the directory name is inside the layer? Bitbake searches all directories right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Yocto layer have a configuration file that describes where to look for recipes `.bb` and recipes append files `.bbappend`:

- `meta-tutorial/conf/layer.conf`:

```sh
...
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"
                              ^
                              |
(Look closely)-----------------
...
```

so, your mistake is that you put your recipe under the path:

```
meta-tutorial/recipe-example/hello
                   ^
                   |
(The mistake)-------
```

So, your recipe should be under:

```
meta-tutorial/recipes-example/hello
                    ^
                    |
(Correction)---------
```